# "right syntax to use near '?' at line 1" error. I am using node to import csv data to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, typescript, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
export async function uploadcsv(req: Request, res: Response) {
try { 
  let stream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path);
  let csvData:any = [];
  let csvStream = fastcsv
    .parse()
    .on("data", function(data:any) {
      csvData.push(data);
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      // remove the first line: header
      csvData.shift();
  
      // connect to the MySQL database
      // save csvData
    });      
  stream.pipe(csvStream);      
  const conn = await connect();   
  let query =
    "INSERT INTO sales9 (Transaction_date,Product,Price,Payment_Type,Name,City,State,Country,Account_Created,Last_Login,Latitude,Longitude) VALUES ?)"; 
  conn.execute(query, [csvData]) 
    .then((onfulfilled: any) => { 
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: "Successfully inserted"
      });
    })
    .catch(error => { 
      res.json({
        err: error
      });    
      throw error 
    });
```

---

I am using nodejs and typescript to import csv data to mysql-server.

```
import { createPool } from "mysql2/promise";
```

I used this in my database.ts file . Everything is working well except the database part and I am getting the following error.

> "message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
>
> "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
> "errno": 1064,
> "sqlState": "42000"

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need  the same number ov value of the number of columns you delcare in INTO clase and the same number of vcar for each param

```
 "INSERT INTO sales9 (Transaction_date,Product,Price,Payment_Type,Name,City,State,Country,Account_Created,Last_Login,Latitude,Longitude) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
 conn.execute(query, csvData);
```

assuming csvDatais valid  array of proper value and not a string

Comment: It saying that it needs 2 arguments only on the execute statement